# Ajuda com exercício de Java

Tags: java, array, orientação-a-objetos, crud

estou com um probleminha em um exercício de JAVA, não consigo arrumar, apesar de ter quase certeza que é bem simples.
É um crud simples:

Abaixo é o código principal

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Crud{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        int max = 4;

        Conta conta[] = new Conta[max];
        Conta c = new Conta();

        int op;
        int indice = 0;

        do{
            System.out.println("1 - criar conta");
            System.out.println("2 - consultar conta");
            System.out.println("7 - sair");
            System.out.print("escolha: ");
            op = scan.nextInt();

            switch(op){
                case 1:
                    if(indice < max){
                        c = new Conta();
                        System.out.println("Número da conta: ");
                        String num = scan.nextLine();
                        c.setNumero(num);
                        scan.nextLine();

                        System.out.println("Saldo: ");
                        double saldo = scan.nextDouble();
                        c.setSaldo(saldo);

                        conta[indice] = c;
                        indice++;
                    }else{
                        System.out.println("");
                        System.out.println("Número limite total de contas atingido!");
                        System.out.println("");
                    }
                    break;

                case 2:
                    if(indice >= 0){
                        System.out.print("Digite o número da conta por favor: ");
                        String busca = scan.nextLine();
                        scan.nextLine();

                        for(int i = 0; i <= indice; i++){
                            if(busca.equals(conta[i].getNumero())){
                                int achou = i;
                                System.out.println("número - " + conta[achou].getNumero());
                                System.out.println("saldo - " + conta[achou].getSaldo());
                            }
                        }
                    }else{
                        System.out.println("");
                        System.out.println("Nenhuma conta cadastrada no momento...");
                        System.out.println("");
                    }
                    break;
                default:
                    System.out.println("Opção inválida");
            }

        }while(op != 7);
    }
}
```

Aqui é o código da classe Conta:

```
public class Conta{
    private String numero;
    private double saldo;

    public String getNumero(){
        return numero;
    }

    public void setNumero(String numero){
        this.numero = numero;
    }

    public double getSaldo(){
        return saldo;
    }

    public void setSaldo(double saldo){
        this.saldo = saldo;
    }
}
```

Não estou conseguindo mostrar o número da conta só o saldo e não estou conseguindo buscar a conta pelo número que é a opção 2.

Comment: Então cara  o problema está no seu indice, dá uma olhada nele que certeza que você consegue resolver essa ai sozinho.

Answer (score 1):

Acontece por que o seu primeiro `Scanner#nextInt()` não consome o ultimo `newline` da expressão, só consome o valor inteiro e deixa o newline inalterado. Por isso o `nextLine` que vc atribui para a variavel `num` retorna vazio. E o que está parando a aplicação é o segundo `nextLine` que não atribui a nada. É algo conhecido já no cenário java, mas sempre batem nele.

A solução seria você consumir esse `newline`logo após o `Scanner#nextInt`:

```
System.out.println("1 - criar conta");
System.out.println("2 - consultar conta");
System.out.println("7 - sair");
System.out.print("escolha: ");
op = scan.nextInt();
```

Ou então, pegar como String e converter em Integer, o que eu aconselho, por que nunca se sabe o que o usuario digitará:

```
System.out.println("1 - criar conta");
System.out.println("2 - consultar conta");
System.out.println("7 - sair");
System.out.print("escolha: ");
try {
    op = Integer.parseInt(scan.nextLine());
} catch (NumberFormatException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    // Ou fazer algo a mais.
}
```

Comment: Oi Gustavo, muito obrigado pela resposta, vou implementar essa dica nos outros códigos que fizer.

Answer (score 1):

Então, o problema é o seguinte, você não esta conseguindo consultar porque ele na realidade não esta salvando o numero da conta, tente criar varias contas e verá que ele mostrará todas, pois como não tem nada no c.getNumero a comparação irá continuar e mostrará apenas o valor de todos os saldos que foram salvos. O problema é algo bem simples, vc o metodo next() em vez do nextLine() para pegar os proximos valores em String, então deve fazer as seguintes substituição: isso

```
 if(indice < max){
                    c = new Conta();
                    System.out.println("Número da conta: ");
                    String num = scan.nextLine();
                    c.setNumero(num);
                    scan.nextLine();

                    System.out.println("Saldo: ");
                    double saldo = scan.nextDouble();
                    c.setSaldo(saldo);

                    conta[indice] = c;
                    indice++;
                }
```

por

```
 if(indice < max){
                    c = new Conta();
                    System.out.println("Número da conta: ");
                  //  scan.nextLine();
                    String num = scan.next();
                    c.setNumero(num);

                    scan.nextLine();

                    System.out.println("Saldo: ");
                    double saldo = scan.nextDouble();
                    c.setSaldo(saldo);

                    conta[indice] = c;
                   System.out.println(num+saldo);
                    indice++;
                }
```

Na hora de salvar, e na ao consultar tbm:

Antes:

```
       if(indice >= 0){
                    System.out.print("Digite o número da conta por favor: ");
                    String busca = scan.nextLine();
                    scan.nextLine();

                    for(int i = 0; i <= indice; i++){
                        if(busca.equals(conta[i].getNumero())){
                            int achou = i;
                            System.out.println("número - " + conta[achou].getNumero());
                            System.out.println("saldo - " + conta[achou].getSaldo());
                        }
                    }
```

Depois

```
  if(indice >= 0){
                    System.out.print("Digite o número da conta por favor: ");
                    String busca = scan.next();


                    for(int i = 0; i < indice; i++){
                        if(busca.equals(conta[i].getNumero())){
                            int achou = i;
                            System.out.println("número - " + conta[achou].getNumero());
                            System.out.println("saldo - " + conta[achou].getSaldo());
                        }
                    }
```

Eu notei que estava retornando um erro de indice no console, o problema era que i ficava em um indice maior do que o ultimo armazenado, a solução é apenas trocar o <= por apenas <.

Comment: Olá André! Valeu cara, funcionou, nunca tinha reparado nessa questão do nextLine(), vou rever algumas coisas, não sábia que o scan.next(); dava certo.